# how can i use a button to change the length of a model?

Tags: scale, arcore, sceneform

I want to add a button that increases the length of my model by pressing it.
what i  am currently doing is getting local scale of model . incrementing it by 0.5f and seting the local scale. but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the scale to the node where you model is attached to:

```
      Node node = new Node();
      node.setParent(anchorNode);
      node.setRenderable(yourRenderable);

      button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
          //make the object twice as large
          node.setLocalScale(new Vector3(2f, 2f, 2f));
      });
```